# Android app is running but exceptions

Tags: android, xml, facebook, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to integrate and run an Android app with Facebook, on Eclipse.

I have just followed all the steps to feature the login button of Facebook.

the app is running fine but as soon as the emulator opens, the app crashes and a list of exceptions follow:

**Exceptions images**

http://s29.postimg.org/ak0cv9w6f/pro1.png

**manifest.xml**

http://s8.postimg.org/3oh1f24lx/image.png

and then my activity_main.xml contains

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Comment: Your LayoutInflater has an error, too. Please show us more code, and check out your LoginButton. That's where the error originates from.

Comment: Hi, you can check the code that I have inserted to test the login button in the links. I'm really not understanding how to proceed. What exactly do you think the problem in the login button code is?

Comment: In the tutorial that I have followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MBS2YvUY2M, there was nothing else beyond this and the login button appeared after the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the facebook SDK, but check if the packagename of your button is correct. In the tutorial you provided, it's called

```
com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
```

try this:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```